# copy all columns of a table in another table having different order of columns

Tags: sql

**copy all columns of a table in another table having different order of columns**

I have two tables named

```
1... product (pid, pname, pdesc, code, stock)
2... product1(pid, pname, img1, img2, pdesc, code, stock)
```

actually there are two more (img1, img2) columns added as required, so new table created product

have tried this out

```
[update product1
set pdesc = (select pdesc from product )]
```

maybe it contains errorful code, (little lack of knowledge in sql)

so just do me a favor, and rewrite it again... please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
insert into product1 (pid, pname, pdesc, code, stock)
select * from product
```

But if `pid` is an auto-increment column you have to leave that one and do

```
insert into product1 (pname, pdesc, code, stock)
select pname, pdesc, code, stock from product
```

And if `img1` and `img2`can't be `null` you have to give them an default value like this:

```
insert into product1 (pname, img1, img2, pdesc, code, stock)
select pname, '', '', pdesc, code, stock from product
```

Comment: unfortunately the column still becomes empty after using code given above......-:(
(not working)

Comment: working now , there was a confusion i had, 
any ways THNK UUU very much

Comment: @ashokkumar Please accept answer if it helped rather than saying "Thank you".